# How can I fix a function that does not take in what it returned?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

have tried to use the return feature so when I call the Function it will use the last generated generation of solutions, but instead, it just uses the randomly generated ones that I used for the first generation and doesn't use the newest, this is an attempt of the Genetic algorithm in python on countdown to find a solution using "*,/,+,-" as operators and six numbers that are generated.

Forgive me if this was an overly simple mistake but I couldn't find anything online as to why it wouldn't use the latest Generation/return properly.

`Mutate`, `SecondGen` and `CurrentPopFitness` are both lists of lists, ([[]]) `Mutate` is ran through a cross over algorithm and mutation is done to it and appended to `SecondGen`, the Fitness scores are then calculated and appended to `CurrentPopFitness` along with the solution that gave that fitness, the 50 best solutions are then appended to `SecondGen` and `Mutate` is set to equal it which it does as I checked via the print at the end, however when it goes onto the next call of the function `Mutate` is back to being what it was at the start of the program.

`Mutate` is made to be 50 long just before the function ends.

I have checked that the second generation at the end is different from what it was for the first generation, However, Mutate (which the contents of the second generation are in at the end) still ends up being the first generation I generated outside of the function; when calling it for the 2nd time and every time after.

```
Target = random.randint(101,1000) 
track2 = 0
Mutate = [[5/6*24-4+3+2][2/5+100*50-7-8]....]
def OffspringMutation(SecondGen,Mutate):
   print(len(Mutate))
   for x in range(50):
      if track2 >= 1:
        SecondGen = SecondGen + 1*[[]]
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][1])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][2])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][3])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][4])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][5])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][6])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][7])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][8])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][9])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][10])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][11])
        track2 += 1
    Mutate = SecondGen    
    return(Mutate)



TruFal = True
while TruFal != False:
    stop = input("Type X to stop the Genetic Algorithm, otherwise press enter")
    if stop == "X":
        TruFal = False
    OffspringMutation(SecondGen,Mutate)
```

The expected result is for `len(Mutate)` to be roughly 60 long at the start (i made it roughly 60 long). Then on the second call of the function(the second generation) `len(Mutate)` should be 50 long and the contents different from what they were set to at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You're not recording the return value of `OffspringMutation`. Although you pass the reference to `Mutate` to the function, this reference is stored in the local variable of the same name you gave it. Therefore any actions to its **contents** will change the original eg: append, slicing, delete, etc. But by doing `Mutate = SecondGen` you are not editing the contents of the reference, you are telling the local variable to point to a different reference, unaffecting the original. By this logic something like `Mutate[:] = SecondGen` (slicing) will change the original, but this is bad practice for a function.

```
Target = random.randint(101,1000) 
track2 = 0
Mutate = [[5/6*24-4+3+2][2/5+100*50-7-8]....]
def OffspringMutation(SecondGen,Mutate):
   print(len(Mutate))
   for x in range(50):
      if track2 >= 1:
        SecondGen = SecondGen + 1*[[]]
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][1])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][2])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][3])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][4])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][5])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][6])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][7])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][8])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][9])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][10])
        SecondGen[track2].append(CurrentPopFitness[x][11])
        track2 += 1
    Mutate = SecondGen    
    return Mutate



TruFal = True
while TruFal != False:
    stop = input("Type X to stop the Genetic Algorithm, otherwise press enter")
    if stop == "X":
        TruFal = False
    Mutate = OffspringMutation(SecondGen,Mutate)
```

also a cleaner method with the same logic as the last loop would be:

```
while True:
    stop = input("Type X to stop the Genetic Algorithm, otherwise press enter")
    Mutate = OffspringMutation(SecondGen,Mutate)
    if stop == "X":
    break
```